# AngularJS ng:submit on 'enter' key

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple form that, upon hitting the 'enter' key, the entered data will be sent and appended to a list in my controller. The code I have is as follows:

controller.js

```
.controller('GenericTodosCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.todos=[];
    $scope.newTodo="";

    function addTodo() {
        alert("hello");
        $scope.todos.push({
            content: $scope.newTodo,
            done: false,
            editing: false
        });
        $scope.newTodo = "";
    };
});
```

main.html

```
<form ng:submit="addTodo()">
    <input name="newTodo" placeholder="Placeholder" type="text">
</form>
```

Currently, when I type in values and hit 'enter' nothing happens (not even the alert). I can't seem to figure out if I should be using "this" instead of $scope for things in controller.js. Does ng:submit require something in the ? Or is this an issue with my javascript instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make `addTodo` part of your `$scope`.

```
$scope.addTodo = function() {
    alert("hello");
    $scope.todos.push({
        content: $scope.newTodo,
        done: false,
        editing: false
    });
    $scope.newTodo = "";
};
```

Also, make sure the value in the input field is actually databound to your `$scope` value by using `ngModel`:

```
<form ng:submit="addTodo()">
    <input ng:model="newTodo" placeholder="Placeholder" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Just starting out with things so thanks for the clear and concise response.

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy learning AngularJS, it's fantastic stuff.